# sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have been following Corey Schafer's video on Flask. I am using the same code as him but I am getting errors when trying to upload profile picture.
This is the route file

```
def save_picture(picture_file):
    hex_key = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(picture_file.filename)
    picture_fn = hex_key + f_ext
    pic_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/profile_pic', picture_fn)
    output_size = (125, 125)
    i = Image.open(picture_file)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.save(pic_path)

    return picture_file

@app.route("/account", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def account():
    form = UpdateAccountForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.picture.data:
            profile_pic = save_picture(form.picture.data)
            current_user.image_file = profile_pic
        current_user.username = form.username.data
        current_user.email = form.email.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('success', 'Your account had been updated!')
        return redirect(url_for('account'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.username.data = current_user.username
        form.email.data = current_user.email

    image_file = url_for('static', filename="profile_pic/" + current_user.image_file)
    return render_template('account.html', title='Account', image_file=image_file, form=form)
```

This is the error displayed.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: UPDATE user SET image_file=? WHERE user.id = ?]
[parameters: (<FileStorage: 'black_board.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>, 1)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return image path.

```
 return pic_path
```